# "start bounty" link only belatedly realizes that I'm out of bounties

Tags: bug, bounties, user-interface

When I have 3 bounties currently running, which is the maximum I can have, I still see the "start bounty" links under questions and can even click them. But even more than that, while the dialog says something like

> You have 3 active bounties, and can start 0 more.

I still can click through the whole series of dialogs, specifying an amount, a builtin reason and a custom reason. But when then clicking  the final "Start Bounty" button nothing happens, since I'm obviously out of bounties. And this seems to be the point that the system finally realizes this, since it seems to hide the "start bounty" link on all the questions.

Now this seems a bit unintuitive (and at first I even thought my bounty might be in some kind of queue, to be started when another bounty slot gets freed). **It should be made clearer that you can't start a bounty because you're out of them, and this should happen earlier than after you clicked through the whole procedure**. Some suggestions:

- Hide the link right away to not even be able to start a bounty at all. Though, this might be a bit confusing, too, if someone isn't aware of having reached the 3 active bounties and wondering where the link went.
- Display some error message when clicking on it instead of the normal dialog. This could either be made once and then subsequently get all the links hidden like it is now, or leave the links and always route to the error message.
- If an extra error message is too much, then maybe adapt the first bounty dialog (which knows if I have more than 0 free slots anyway), to just disable any further continuation of the bounty procedure.

Comment: Eh, that's strange. Either it was never the case before and just a recent bug, or I haven't noticed it till now, despite the fact I had 3 active bounties not once.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if the 'Start  a Bounty' was missing or grey/italicized if you run out, and ***if*** you get past that then the "Bounty Amount" should be a Pulldown on the 'Type of Bounty' list of choices. It's odd that you choose the amount first and then go to a new dialog and are offered a list of reasons. Upon seeing the reasons available to offer a Bounty you might want to offer a different amount. If there's no "Are you Sure?" then everything you need should be presented simultaneously, not in spoonfuls.